# How to use auto scroll view in react native with dote?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autoscaling, auto, autoscroll

**here is my code**

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { scale, verticalScale } from "react-native-size-matters"
import { RFPercentage} from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

const dummyData =
    [{
        title: 'Get instant loans with approvals',
        uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWo3YRChZ3ADpZ7rEfQu1RvBOu9NMWZIMZBaH-a1CArXqx6nLX',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
        id: 1
    },
    // {
    //     title: 'Get money in wallet or bank account',
    //     uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQN0NcV2epN147CiVfr_VAwsbU3VO8rJU0BPphfU9CEsVWa-kRX',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
    //     id: 2
    // },
    // {
    //     title: 'Refer & earn exciting gifts',
    //     uri: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUbS4LNT8rnIRASXO6LGFSle7Mhy2bSLwnOeqDMivYTb2cgTJg',//require('../img/1page.jpg'),
    //     id: 3
    // }
]

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

    const renderItem=({item})=>{
        return(
            <View>
                <Image source={{uri:item.uri}}style={styles.img} />
                <View style={styles.dotView}>
                    <View style={styles.dot}/>
                    <View style={styles.dot}/>
                    <View style={styles.dot}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.contanier}>
            <View style={styles.imgView}>
                <Image source={require('../img/homelogo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
            </View>

            <View style={{marginBottom:8}}>
                <FlatList
                    data={dummyData}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.btnview}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("PermissionPage")}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.btntext}>Get Started</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Home;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contanier: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    imgView: {
        marginTop: verticalScale(10),
        marginLeft: 20,
    },
    logo: {
        width: scale(70),
        height: verticalScale(70),
        borderRadius: 50,
        // position: 'absolute'
    },
    btnview: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop:10,
    },
    btn: {
        width: scale(250),
        height: verticalScale(55),
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#2192FF',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    btntext: {
        fontSize: RFPercentage(3.20),// fontSize: RFValue(17, 680),
        color: '#fff',
        fontWeight: '600',
        fontFamily: 'Roboto'
    },
    img:{
        width:scale(300),
        height:verticalScale(450),
    },
    text:{
        fontSize:RFPercentage(3),
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'#000',
        textAlign:'center'
    },
    dotView:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'center',
        marginBottom:8
    },
    dot:{
        width:scale(8),
        height:verticalScale(8),
        backgroundColor:'#2192ff',
        borderRadius:20,
        marginLeft:5
    }
})
```

here is output I want

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdjfm.jpg

I'm creating new app in app home page have auto scroll img but I don't know how to use it and do it
I'm fine some lib but i don't use any lib I want without lib.

I'm seen may qustion on internet but I'm not find soution what I want

any one can help me ?